# Json Key Value pair; Value has string array

Tags: jquery, json

I have a Json Object; It s return item error list.

```
[{"Key":"txt_Field","Value":["Error Msg1","Error Msg2"]}]
```

Jquery Code;

```
        $.each(errors, function (key, value) {
            var obj = errors[key].Key;
            //alert(errors[key].Key);
            for (message in value) {
                alert(message.Value);
            }
            //$.each(value, function (key, value) {
            //    alert(key + ' : ' + value);
            //});
        });
```

I want to get error message in ul li tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an array of object(s). In your code `value` refers to each object in the array. `$.each` doesn't work like `for ... in` loops where you use the keys for accessing object properties. You can simply use the `value` parameter.

```
 var $ul = $('ul');
 $.each(errors, function (key, value) {
     // `key` here is the index
     // `value` refers to each array element
     $.each(value.Value, function(_, error) {
         $ul.append($('<li>', { text: error })); 
     });
 });
```

The above code snippet at first selects and caches the target `ul` element. You can change the selector if you have several `ul` elements. If there is no `ul` element you can generate one by using `$('<ul></ul>')`.